# Ratio 1:1 for exact matching using MatchIt package

Tags: r, match, matching

```
library(MatchIt)

df <- data.frame(lalonde)

m.out1 <- matchit(treat ~ age + race + educ, data = lalonde,
                  method = "exact")

m.data1<-match.data(m.out1)
```

I would like to know how I can get the same size for both the control and treatment samples after running an exact matching with MatchIt package. Ideally, I would like to randomly pick a control if a treated unit has been matched to more than one control.
My real dataset is not lalonde. It is actually an extremely large one. So I might have many controls associated with a treated unit and I want to draw one randomly for each treated unit.

Comment: There is a more streamlined package that I would recommend: `Matching`. Install it, open `help('Match', package='Matching')` and read `ties` section which might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I tried to use Matching but I wasn't able to make an exact matching with it.

Comment: Actually, you would only need to do `Match(..., exact=TRUE)`, wouldn't you? And `ties=FALSE` to get the controls randomly broken.

Comment: They don't have any example for exact matching in the documentation. I only found examples using Propensity Score.
I tried variations of:
```data(lalonde)
X=cbind(lalonde$age)
out <- Match(Tr=lalonde$treat, X=X, data = lalonde, exact=TRUE)```

(And also tried using Matchby instead of Match)

Comment: Do you know what command I should run?

Comment: See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71924873/6574038).

Answer (score 1):

For exact matching you could use this code.

```
library(Matching)
data("lalonde")

Y <- lalonde$re78
Tr <- lalonde$treat
X <- lalonde[setdiff(names(lalonde), c('re78', 'treat'))]

set.seed(42)  ## comment out for FIXING the ties
rmtch <- Match(Y=Y, Tr=Tr, X=X, exact=TRUE, ties=FALSE)
summary(rmtch)
# Estimate...  1678.6 
# SE.........  981 
# T-stat.....  1.7111 
# p.val......  0.087055 
# 
# Original number of observations..............  445 
# Original number of treated obs...............  185 
# Matched number of observations...............  55 
# Matched number of observations  (unweighted).  55 
# 
# Number of obs dropped by 'exact' or 'caliper'  130 

str(rmtch)  ## what is stored in Match object

rmtch$index.control  ## indices of control units
# [1] 261 254 188 279 288 317 323 280 186 311 305 234 337 302 219 345 234 328
# [19] 271 218 253 249 339 271 339 344 351 253 328 339 255 217 254 197 254 284
# [37] 266 252 253 280 208 226 209 354 204 282 350 296 202 247 219 330 347 280
# [55] 344
```

If you re-run the code, you will see that the IDs change slightly, which they would probably do more clearly if the dataset was larger.

To fix the randomization of the control units you may use `set.seed()`. For handling ties deterministically use `ties=FALSE` (see `?Match` help page).

Comment: Thank you! But how would I be able to get a new dataframe with both control and matched units? I can't understand how I can use rmtch$index.control to get a new dataset as tidy as the one MatchIt presents with both types of units.
The thing about the IDs changing is that I would later want to merge this dataset to another based on the ids.

Comment: @Rnovice There's also a `index.treated`. Have you looked into `str(rmtch)`? In the Value section there's a nice guide how to do this, perhaps you want `rbind(lalonde[rmtch$index.treated, ], lalonde[rmtch$index.control, ]`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do 1:1 nearest neighbor matching with exact matching constraints:

```r
m.out1 <- matchit(treat ~ age + race + educ, data = lalonde,
                  method = "nearest",
                  # Here the exact matching constraint.
                  exact = ~ age + race + educ)
```

If you are doing coarsened exact matching, there is an option already built in to request this which is by setting `k2k = TRUE`:

```r
m.out1 <- matchit(treat ~ age + race + educ, data = lalonde,
                  method = "cem", k2k = TRUE,
                  cutpoints = 0)
```

Setting `cutpoints = 0` requests exact matching (no coarsening).